# MySQL Query to remove data between 2 specific strings

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like a MySQL query to achieve the following :

I have 10000 rows that look like this

```
Source 1::https://domainxyz.com//public/dist/s2q1sd65az7r/index.html||Source 2::https://domainabc.com/embed-8eel8v83lefs.html||Source 3::https://domainqsd.com/v/w1qy8g81w6||Source 5:://domainwxc.com/embed2.php?link=5fUE7Mo%25
```

Only the links are different from one row to another

I'd like to remove all content related to Source 1

That content would be anything between "Source 1" and "||" (including the removal of the string "source 1")

So in my exemple, that would removing this :

```
Source 1::https://domainxyz.com//public/dist/index.html
```

**PS : it also possible that "Source 1" data has no "||" at the end** (when the data is at the end of the ligne)

Comment: That's a database schema in urgent need of a proper relational structure.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is or isn't working? Please read over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question with more detail. SO isn't a place to request free work to be done for you, but rather to help you solve problems related to code that you already have.

Comment: I already tried DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE  (post_content liKe '%domainxyz.com%')
But the problem is it removes everything until the end of the line.
I need removal to stop at "||"

I wanted then to do it in 2 steps and remove "source 1::" after that.

But the ideal would something like i explained in the post

Comment: `DELETE` does one thing and one thing only: Remove rows from your database. What you're looking for is `UPDATE`.

Comment: I think `patindex` is gonna work here... but we do require schema and maybe some demo data for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(concat(str, '||'), 'Source 1::[^|]*[|][|]', '')
from (select 'Source 1::https://domainxyz.com//public/dist/s2q1sd65az7r/index.html||Source 2::https://domainabc.com/embed-8eel8v83lefs.html||Source 3::https://domainqsd.com/v/w1qy8g81w6||Source 5:://domainwxc.com/embed2.php?link=5fUE7Mo%25' as str
     ) t
```

Or alternatively as:

```
select regexp_replace(str, 'Source 1::[^|]*([|][|]|$)', '')
```

Comment: Thank you for your proposition :)
regexp only works on mysql 8 and I can't upgrade to it, because to make it work with VestaCP is on another level of trouble :/